# MANIFEST.in not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, manifest, pypi

I'm trying to publish a package to PyPI, but while creating the `MANIFEST` file I'm facing this problem-

```
>>>check-manifest -c    
lists of files in version control and sdist do not match!
missing from sdist:
  src/LICENSE
no MANIFEST.in found
don't know how to come up with rules matching any of the files, sorry!
```

Note - I've added all the files to version control and had run `python setup.py sdist` command earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating it manually and it worked.
I don't know why `create-manifest --create` didn't work up though.